# problem with html editor

Tags: asp.net, ajax, controls

I used Html Editor with firefox on my pc. I switched pcs and I tested my site again.. The HTML editor appears completely messed up across browsers ..It doesnt even look as good as it 
is on the original pc i deployed it.
The question is why? And should I use ajax at all instead of jquery?

All the pages markup:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/YourGuruMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PostEdit.aspx.cs" Inherits="PostEdit" %>
```

<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor" tagprefix="cc1" %>

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>

    <cc1:Editor 
        ID="Editor1" 
        Width="850px"  
        Height="400px"
        runat="server"/>
    <br />
    <asp:Button
        id="btnSubmit"
        Text="Submit"
        Runat="server" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />






<br />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="Editor1" ErrorMessage="אין להשאיר שדות רקים" 
    ForeColor="#CC0000"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Some code or a link would help.

Comment: Code would definatly help, it sounds like you may have been referencing code by folder path that doesn't exist on the other machines.

Comment: I will present you with the code..But the code is identical to the code of the web application that i run on the original pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) This is a much deeper problem. You probably need to add more rules to your css stylesheet. If you want the site to look the same across different browsers, you have to look into **cross browser support** and **cross browser compatibility**.

2.) The jQuery library has a full suite of AJAX capabilities. There is no need to use self-made js functions to create AJAX calls. Stick with jQuery.

Comment: i will dumb ajax and adapt query. Thanks for the advice